# Building a bitbake component locally

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am writing a component that goes into the yocto build, but during development I don't want to build the entire image. I want to checkout my component(in its own GIT repo), build it using the cross-compiler used for building the entire tree, and test that before checking in(devtest) and building the entire filesystem for system test. I have not found a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is to build the SDK?

Run

```
bitbake - c populate_sdk <image-name>
```

that'll give you a nice SDK in a tarball. Then you execute that tarball to install it on you desired location.

In the shell where you're developing your application, you source the `environment-....` file in the installed location. Now everything is configured to crosscompile, as long as you're using eg CC instead of directly calling gcc.